# Streaming Cloudformation Events

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I was wondering if anybody has found away to stream AWS Cloudformation stack events to an external source? e.g. via SNS.

I am ultimately looking to create a dashboard for our office that will show recent Cloudformation events along side other information.

We have some Jenkins scripts that will update a stack (new AMI on our application stack for example) and it would be good to see, at a glance, what stage CF is at for modifying and replacing resources in response to the update.

Has anybody achieved this?

Thanks,
Jim

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as my knowledge goes you currently have 3 options:

#### PUSH

CFN supports custom resources. So you can create SNS Topic and "ask" CFN to push events to it with custom variables. The consumer of the SNS could be anything starting from AWS Lambda to your own script.

```
  "Subscriber" : {
      "Type" : "Custom::Subscribe",
      "Version" : "1.0",
      "Properties" : {
        "ServiceToken" : { "Ref" : "CustomResourceTopic" },
        "XXXX": "YYY"
      }
    }
```

#### PULL

Similar to "long puling" technique you just call AWS CloudFormation and compare changes.

`aws cloudformation describe-events ....`

#### AWS Config

This AWS service is responsible for "watching"  changes in your account. This a pretty new service and so far has some limitations in terms of "what" it can watch. You can hook it up to SNS and achieve the same thing.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to create a separate SNS topic as a custom resource for this.
CloudFormation's create,update and delete stack APIs allow for an SNS topic to be passed in and all stack events get published to those topics
see
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/APIReference/API_CreateStack.html
Specifically:

> The Simple Notification Service (SNS) topic ARNs to publish stack
>   related events. You can find your SNS topic ARNs using the SNS console
>   or your Command Line Interface (CLI)."

I publish stack events into my own shell using an SNS topic linked to an SQS queue that I just poll. More info :
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/cli/sns_subscribe.html

I hope this helps